# Access TextBox String from static method

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to access wpf ui elements from a static method? I'm trying to access a textbox string from a static method to no avail

Comment: You can access only static members form your static mehod..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be impossible. Your static method can run while the textbox doesn't exist because there is no instance of your form.
Static methods are designed to be able to run without any instance.
Quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_method#Static_methods):

> Therefore, a static method cannot
>   refer to a specific instance of the
>   class (i.e. it cannot refer to this,
>   self, Me, etc.)

Comment: Use `<blockquote>` to display quotes.

Comment: That Wiki quote doesn't apply in this case - it is referring to a static method trying to refer to the "instance" of the class it is in.

Answer (score 1):

Need more code to give a better answer.

e.g. if you pass in a Window parameter to the static method or if you pass in the ViewModel object that has the property to which your textbox binds to, I'd say you would be able to affect the WPF UI from your static method.